# Unforgeability and type of adversary

Tags: signature, provable-security, forgery

When trying to prove the security of an asymmetric signature, for instance, for existential (or strong) unforgeability against chosen messages attack, do we need to consider the signer as a possible adversary?

Answer (score 7):

**No**, the signer is per definition in possession of the secret signing key and thus can always produce signatures for **any** message of his choice.

Consequently, a notion of unforgeability is not meaningful with respect to the signer. For a signature scheme one requires *unforgeability* for parties who are **not** in possession of the secret signing key but only the public verification key.

You may also look at [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/relation-between-attack-and-attack-model/11280#11280) for a more detailed discussion on *attacks* and *attack models* for digital signature schemes.